# Love DND -- Can It Be Applied to Individual Contacts?

Tags: ios, settings, voicemail

I think do not disturb is a great improvement in iOS 6. I have a super annoying persistent caller but I need to hear their voicemails. Is there any way to have calls from their phone number forward directly to voicemail?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a silent ringtone to that caller?

Comment: I guess that would accomplish something but what I really want is for this particular caller to leave a voicemail. I just don't want to spend time on the phone with them. So a silent ring tone doesn't stop the vibration or the front light. But it's a good thought.

Answer (score 2):

Your service provider should be able to provide that service.  The number would be stopped at the call side, and redirected before it gets to your phone.

Give them a call.